# Send and Receive messages between registered users

Tags: asp.net

I have a website I am implementing and I want to add a functionality to send and receive messages between registered users. What is the best way to go about implementing it in C# asp.net?

Thanks

Comment: what ASP.NET version? it's nice if you specify the .NET version that you are using.

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement such functionality is create a new Table in your database, and for example, called `tblPrivatemessages` containing:

```
message_id    int PK
fromUser      int
toUser        int
subject       nvarchar(100)
message       text
crete_date    datetime
read_date     datetime (accept NULL)
```

And create a simple CRUD form to use this table.